# Postman specify different working directory per workspace or collection

Tags: postman

I have different postman collections per project repository, and every time I switch collections to run some tests they break because they depend on resources (files, images sent as part of request bodies) versioned separately in different repositories (you can see each repository as a different working directory).

At the Postman General settings I can change the Working dir Location by specifying a path, however I have to update this path for the specific collection repository dir everytime I want to run a collection.

Is there a way to set a specific Working Dir for each collection (or workspace) basis?

Another option could be to specify resources relative to the collection file (but not by setting a absolute path as each developer might check out the code in different places=. The idea would be that I don't need to change the location every time for each request. Is there a way to do that?